# AzerothCore: how to change the time after which client is disconnected when being idle?

Tags: azerothcore

Using [AzerothCore](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk), some clients stay logged for some time after shutting down che client application non-gracefully (e.g. pressing `alt+f4` or killing the client process).

Is there a way to change this behaviour? For example reducing the time after clients get disconnected after being ide?

Answer (score 0):

This is configurable in `worldserver.conf`:

```
#
#    SocketTimeOutTime
#        Description: Time (in milliseconds) after which a connection being idle on the character
#                     selection screen is disconnected.
#        Default:     900000 - (15 minutes)

SocketTimeOutTime = 900000

#
#    SocketTimeOutTimeActive
#        Description: Time (in milliseconds) after which an idle connection is dropped while
#                     logged into the world.
#                     The client sends keepalive packets every 30 seconds. Values <= 30s are not recommended.
#        Default:     60000 - (1 minute)

SocketTimeOutTimeActive = 60000
```

changing those settings will make it, then `.reload config` or restart the worldserver.

Be aware that:

> Values <= 30s are not recommended.

so one user can still have the time to return online without side effects in case of client crash.

Thanks **@Viste** for the suggestion.